# Can I get the Intent to start a Service by Service name?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

Is there anyway to get the Intent to start a Service if I just know the Service's ComponentName? The following code snippet can get all running Services and their ComponentNames, but if I want to bind to a Service, I need an Intent instead of ComponentName, so how to get the Intent? By the way, assume the Service is provided by another APP and can't be started by explicit Intent.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityManager
        .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
    RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo = serviceList.get(i);
    ComponentName name = serviceInfo.service;

    ... ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can start any service with componentname and package name.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("service packagename", "service componentname"));
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

thats it...